# Why does the python editor "Idle" reference two Python installations?

Tags: python, idle

I have installed python 2.6 with ArcGIS 10.0 but also Python 2.7 for use with gdal.

I have a problem at the moment with the editor "IDLE". When I right-click on a .py script, the idle editor references python 2.7 as shown on the first line here:

> Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

Subsequently, all scripts fail with the following error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung.

However, if I type "idle" in my Windows 7 search field, and start idle independently without a script, the editor starts in this mode:

> Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

So how can I make idle reference Python 2.6 when right-clicking on the script?

Comment: You need to change the default program you open python scripts with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly use the 32 bit version of python 2.6.  You can do this by running simple batch files like this to run stand alone:

```
start C:\Python26\ArcGIS10\python.exe C:\Path\to\your_python_file.py
```

EDIT:  Sorry, I misread your original post. It is not recommended to have two different versions of Python on your machine though.  It can cause some issues but if you're careful you should be able to work around them.  It should always call the appropriate version when running from within ArcMap or Catalog.  Python IDLE will usually default to the most recent version installed which in your case will be the 2.7 version.